# Laravel fluent insert with multiple values only inserts the first value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I am trying to run a single seeder class:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class CourseTableSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('courses')->insert(
            ['name' => 'PhD'],
            ['name' => 'Master'],
            ['name' => 'Bachelor'],
            ['name' => 'Foundation'],
            ['name' => 'ESL']
        );
    }

}
```

I execute the command with:

```
art db:seed --class CourseTableSeeder
```

and I expect to see the five values in the database, however, I only see the very first one 'phd'.

I have tried debugging this by running `->toSql()` on the insert but I don't think it's possible and I receive the following error as insert most likely returns a boolean, so not chainable

```
[2018-07-23 15:35:45] local.ERROR: Call to a member function toSql() on boolean {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Call to a member function toSql() on boolean at C:\\laragon\\www\
```

eports\database\seeds\CourseTableSeeder.php:15)

As I couldn't easily figure out how the insert method worked via digging into the framework's source, I began to wonder if `DB::table('table_name')->insert()` accepted multiple inserts via an array and I managed to find examples of this in the framework's testing suite, for example:

```
DB::table('posts_tags')->insert([
    ['post_id' => $post->id, 'tag_id' => 200, 'flag' => ''],
    ['post_id' => $post->id, 'tag_id' => 300, 'flag' => 'exclude'],
    ['post_id' => $post->id, 'tag_id' => 400, 'flag' => ''],
]);
```

source: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/tests/Integration/Database/EloquentBelongsToManyTest.php#L539

So I am guessing I am not doing anything wrong. Any ideas on what the issue is and how I may debug what's going wrong as I have exhausted the options known to me. Also, while running the whole thing no errors show up in the console or log file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `insert()` is missing some `[]` syntax in it. Compare yours

```
->insert(
  ["name" => "..."]
);
```

to the documentation

```
->insert([
  ["post_id" => "..."]
]);
```

So, the documentation is suggesting to pass a single array, containing an array for each record you want inserted, while your implementation is passing multiple arrays.